# Get max length of value inside a list which contains other lists

Tags: python, list

I got a list with keys and other lists. I want to create a function that checks the list for the longest value(string). It should give me back the longest string as number. I found nothing useful on the internet.  only the strings with the key (value) need to be checked.
Output : It should count each character of the longest value(string).

Hope you can help me.

List:

```
 [{'name': 'title', 'value': 'titel{TM} D3', 'is_on_label': 1},
 {'name': 'DK in', 'value': '24V max 2.5A', 'is_on_label': 1,
 'id_configuration': 79,

 'options': [{'value': '30V max 3A', 'id_configuration_v': '1668'},
             {'value': 'none', 'id_configuration_v': '1696'}]}]
```

function:

```
def checkLenFromConfigs(self, configs):
   max_lenght = max(map(len, configs))
   return max_lenght
```

Comment: What's the desired output you're looking for here? also, would we count `id_configuration_v` even though it's a key, not a value?

Comment: @rv.kvetch Output : It should count each character of the longest value(string).
id_configuration_v is later used to store the right conig in a database.

Comment: @wimsenOG for given list , show us what you mean by longest

Comment: Having an arbitrarily nested list makes this tricky; I don't think you can do it with `max` unless you flatten the list first into a single list of all the value strings.  (At which point it'd just be `max(flattened_list, key=len)`.)

Comment: @eshirvana all with the key value

Comment: @Samwise please let me know if you have a better idea. it don't have to be with max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recursively search for all `values` in your data structure:

```
data = [{
        "name": "title",
        "value": "titel{TM} D3",
        "is_on_label": 1
    },
    [{
        "name": "title",
        "value": "titel{TM} D3",
        "is_on_label": 1,
        "sub_options": [
            {
                "value": "30V max 3A",
                "id_configuration_v": "1668"
            },
            {
                "value": "none none none none",
                "id_configuration_v": "1696"
            }
        ]
    }], 
    {
        "name": "DK in",
        "value": "24V max 2.5A",
        "is_on_label": 1,
        "id_configuration": 79,
        "options": [{
                "value": "30V max 3A",
                "id_configuration_v": "1668"
            },
            {
                "value": "none",
                "id_configuration_v": "1696"
            }
        ]
    }
]



def recur(data, count):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            count = recur(item, count)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            if k == 'value':
                count.append(len(v))
            else:
                count = recur(v, count)
    return count

result = recur(data, [])
print(max(result))
```

Out:

```
19
```